# How to know which x values to use in predict method in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, predict

I have fitted a linear model:

```
f <- lm(y ~ x)
```

From that I used the predict method

```
p <- predict(f)
```

But the predict method does not deliver the expected result. In the following image I have marked red the fitted range.

```
lines(x, y, col="red")
```

Blue are the predicted values

```
lines(x, p, col="blue")
```

But the predicted values does not start at the expected point. I had expected that the first y value of the predicted point starts at the same point as the first fitted value.

So now I know why this is not happen. Because I predicted the unknown y values from known x values. But how can I easily achieve that the blue line is moved down, so that you can see the blue line is associated to the red line? Thus how I know which x values are to use?

[image: plot of fitted values and predicted values]

Answer (score 0):

When you omit the `newdata` argument from the `predict` function, you use the fitted values of your model instead (see `?predict.lm`). If you take the smallest x-value from your data and draw a vertical line up, you can see this, i.e.

```
abline(v=min(x), col=4, lty=3)
```

Comment: This is clear and not exactly what I asked for. But this carry me to the conclusion that I will not adjust the x range.